# useRef reference provided via react context is not updated correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-ref

I asked a similar question some days ago, but the question led into a different direction.
Since the actual problem still exists, I would still need your help.

Basically I have a bunch of react components, that consume a react context.
One of these components renders an image and setting the useref reference provided by my context.

The Context:

```
export const ProjectContext: FC<ContextProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const imgRef = useRef(null);
  const [imageRef, setImgRef] = useState<HTMLImageElement | null>(imgRef.current);

  const setImageRef = useCallback(
    (ref: HTMLImageElement) => {
      setImgRef(ref);
    },
    [imageRef]
  );

  return (
    <PrjContext.Provider
      value={{
        imageRef,
        setImageRef
      }}>
      {children}
    </PrjContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

that imageRef is used by several other components for some fancy manipulation and calculation.

The Component that sets the reference:

```
const Component = () => {
  const { imageRef, setImageRef } = useContext(PrjContext);
  const { imageBase64String: imgSrc } = projectData || {};

  if (!imgSrc) return null;

  return (
    <Image
        id="analysis_image"
        draggable={false}
        ref={(ref) => {
            setImageRef(ref);
        }}
        src={imgSrc}
        isHorizontalImage={true}
    />
  );
};

export default ImageAnalysis;
```

Now things are getting quite strange. I had some struggles in the past and ended up with that useRef / useState combination. That worked quite well.
After a page reload, the calculation is working, the ref seems to be set correctly.

image properties:

```
height: 1179
naturalHeight: 743
naturalWidth: 1000
width: 1587
```

If I open the same page in a new browser tab, the properties are completely messed up:

```
height: 0
naturalHeight: 0
naturalWidth: 0
width: 1587
```

after reloading the page, everything is normal again.

Even worse:

On safari, the normal render already shows the messed up properties.

It seems as if the imageRef (provided by the context) is not updated properly.
Does anybody know where I made the mistake?

Best Wishes

Edit: the imgSrc is loaded from an external source, db request. The image is behind a loading animation, when the request is finished, the image itself is rendered

Edit2: It seems as if the setter would receive an incorrect ref object, sometime, the parseable values (height, width, depending on the aspect ratio) are unexpected 0 :(

Comment: In the code you've provided it doesn't actually appear that you're actually using the `ref` you declare with `useRef` for anything other than to set a default value for `useState`. I'm not 100% what you're going for but I think you can achieve what you want without the `useRef`. Your issue with inconsistent renders could potentially be due to React strict mode which is run in dev environment. You could try adding the following condition inside your `useCallback` to resolve it: `if(ref !== null) { setImgRef(ref); }`

Comment: What type of component is `<Image />` ?  also, where and **when** are you using `imageRef` in your `<Component />` ?

Comment: I don't completely understand your code. But I wonder why you don't use setState({...}) in your code. Do your components rerender correctly?

Comment: if im not wrong with this.. a ref is a connection between the given variable you define with useRef and the element. why can it have more than one type? shouldnt it always be string for text.. int for number etc... you seem to have more types for 1 field

Comment: @epsilon42

I already tried to set the ref, only if the ref exists, but it does not solve my issue.
That useRef is indeed superflous, already removed it.

mlegrix

<Image /> is a styled component
<Component /> itself does not use the ref, it only contains the images (and other things)

Other components use that ref, provided via setState, to do some calculations. 
Regarding the "when":

All Components, including the image, are behind a loading animation. After all data is fetched, the images is rendered and at the same time, other components are relying on that image reference

Comment: @habrewning
Well I do use setStates in my components. These components do rerender correctly,  as long as I do not open the page in a new tab (via deep link).

Comment: @Daniel I'm not quite sure, if I understand your question correctly. useRef can store any kind of data, numbers, strings, ref objects (such as provided via the ref property of a rect element). In these cases (and I guess in all others, too) it can be defined or not defined

Comment: @epsilon42 Tried to disable the strict mode, still have the same issue

Comment: @Dwain, remember that Ref don't work on Functional Components, you have to use ForwardRef in that case. Furthermore, the `ref.current` property is set only after the HTML Element is mounted in the DOM, and painted to the screen. Therefore getting any information from the `ref.current` should be done inside a `useEffect` hook after the first render. So make sure you use of `ref.current` are in effects. Hopes this helps

Comment: sorry, but why do you need to useState for ref? Isn't it simplier just to pass plain ref and set it in the component like ref={passedRef} ?

Comment: @mlegrix we should not use ref in useEffect - useEffect simply doesn't trigger on refs